# I am getting the error as per the screenshot attached, unable to go ahead

Tags: boot

I ran `fsck /dev/sda2` and at the end I entered 'exit' and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that I am getting:

```
end kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
```

[image: https://ibb.co/Wv5Pwy2]

Comment: Rebooting is again showing the same screen.

Comment: Is `/dev/sda2` your system partition?  Because as it stands from this screen, the target file system you're trying to boot to doesn't have any of the requisite init systems to boot up, and as such is totally fubar.  You will need an Ubuntu Live USB (installer ISO for Desktop written to USB) or a DVD of the Ubuntu Installer to boot to in order to review the system and see what fubar'd.

Comment: @Thomas ward - I do have iso in usb, could you please help how to go ahead?? I am new to ubuntu. I am not sure what to do?